# python MYSQLdb execute() result doesn't match fetch result

Tags: python, mysql-python

Here is our code:

```
db = get_connection()
try:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    if not cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM test WHERE name = %s", ['name']) > 0:
        return None
    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
finally:
    db.close()
```

But sometimes, it will cause some excption.

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
>
> return cursor.fetchone()[0]

What's problem with our codes?

Comment: try this: if not (cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM test WHERE name = %s", ['name']) > 0):

Comment: Which kind of cursor are you using? I.e. is `get_connection` setting a `cursorclass`?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo I use the `sqlalchemy.create_engine`. It's a connection pool provided by `sqlalchemy`